# Can I feed an ical calendar to Kal or Tapku within my iphone app?

Tags: icalendar, tapku

Actually I am using Xcode 4.5.1 and would like to incorporate either Kal or Tapku to provide a calendar in my app.  However, I dont want to edit or add any events, I just want the calendar to show the events from an xml/ical public calendar

Comment: Basically I want a calendar in my iOS app.  I know that Kal and Tapku exist out there already to integrate within an iOS app.  However I don't want to create/add/edit events, I just want the user to see a calendar which is actually pulling its data from a google calendar.  I am trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the eventkit and the google api objective-c client

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m